# CRC-32 field in zip

Tags: c, zip

I am designing a zip-unzip utility using C. There is a crc-32 code field. Is it of compressed data or uncompressed data?

Comment: **It is just a basic utility and is not intended to replace the original utitlity.**

Comment: What does the zip format specification say that you use to implement your utility with?

Comment: Nothing! that's the reason I asked the ques

Comment: Well, if it's one of those two alternatives, compute both CRCs and see which one a standard zip utility can grok without complaining about a CRC error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the CRC-32 of the uncompressed data. In other words, it would be the CRC-32 of the file's original contents before being compressed. [Zlib](http://zlib.net/) has a [minizip](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/minizip/) contribution which is a small zip/unzip implementation written in C. In [zip.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/minizip/zip.c) you can see in the function `zipWriteInFileInZip` that it is generating the crc of the buffer passed in that should contain the file's original contents.